# Writing musical pitches

Tags: macros, music

Is there a package or macro that allows me to easily typeset musical pitches, like the following:

[image]

? Indeed I would like to have subscripts for the octaves. Let's say

```
$\mathrm{E}\flat_3$
```

How would I write a macro producing this output, when the invocation is

```
\note{Eb3}
```

Like:

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{???}
```

I would have to take the string apart, the first char goes into `\mathrm`, then there is an optional second char `#` or `b`, followed by a digit.

Comment: Do you know this http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musictex ?

Comment: I read about musictex. I don't want to typeset scores, I use Lilypond for that. Also it says it's for TeX not LaTeX. I just need to have some inline functions such as the note names above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only quirk is that you have to use brackets `[]` rather than braces `{}` to enclose the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\note[#1#2#3]{#1\if b#2$\flat_#3$\else\if#2##$\sharp_#3$\else$_#2$\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\note[Eb3]
\note[A2]
\note[F#4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would prefer the use of braces to brackets, then the following modification would do.  It renames the `\note` from the above code as `\xnote` and creates a newcommand `\note` to do the argument translation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\note[1]{\xnote[#1]}
\def\xnote[#1#2#3]{#1\if b#2$\flat_#3$\else\if#2##$\sharp_#3$\else$_#2$\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\note{Eb3}
\note{A2}
\note{F#4}
\end{document}
```

---

Since egreg's answer seems to go beyond what the OP asked, providing reasonable behavior when either argument 2, argument 3, or arguments 2 and 3 are missing, I felt it incumbent to do the same (EDITED using Qrrbrrbr...brbrbrl's suggestion to enclose subscript definitions in braces, which will facilitate two-digit octave numbers, shown in last line of output):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\note[1]{\xnote#1\relax\relax\relax}
\def\xnote#1#2#3\relax{#1\if#2\relax\else\if b#2$\flat\if#3\relax%
  \else_{#3}\fi$\else\if###2$\sharp\if#3\relax\else_{#3}\fi$\else$_{#2}$\fi\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\note{Eb3}
\note{A2}
\note{C#}
\note{A}
\note{Eb}
\note{F#4}

\note{F{14}}
\note{F#{14}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How I like when an answer to a question asking for a package has only a few lines of code! :-)

Comment: If you use `_{#3}` instead of `_#3` (though I prefer `\textsubscript`) it would be possible to use `\note{F#14}` but `4` would be dropped if `\node{F14}` has been used.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I revised, based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Some slow scanning of the argument is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % for \textsubscript
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\emit@note#1\@nil}
\def\emit@note#1#2\@nil{%
  \textup{#1}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\emit@@note#2\@nil}%
}
\def\emit@@note{\@ifnextchar##{\emit@sharp}{\emit@@@note}}
\def\emit@sharp#1{$\sharp$\emit@@@note}
\def\emit@@@note{\@ifnextchar b{$\flat$\emit@@@@note}{\emit@@@@note{}}}
\def\emit@@@@note#1#2\@nil{\textsubscript{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\note{A}
\note{A#}
\note{Ab}
\note{A2}
\note{A#2}
\note{Ab2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

By kind request, here's a possible LaTeX3 implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % for \textsubscript

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\note}{m}
 {
  \emit_note:n { #1 }
 }

% a variable
\tl_new:N \l_emit_specs_tl

% internal main function
\cs_new_protected:Npn \emit_note:n #1
 {% Get the first token
  \emit_textup:x { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
  % Get the rest and pass control to \emit_do_specs:n
  \tl_set:Nx \l_emit_specs_tl { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_emit_specs_tl
   {
    \emit_do_specs:o { \l_emit_specs_tl \q_stop }
   }
 }

% We can't use \textup{ \tl_head:n { #1 } } because of possible #
\cs_new_protected:Npn \emit_textup:n #1
 {
  \textup { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \emit_textup:n { x }

% Check if the first token is # or b
% and take appropriate actions
% Then hand the remainder to \emit_range:w
\cs_new_protected:Npn \emit_do_specs:n #1
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF ##
   { $\sharp$ \emit_range:w }
   {
    \peek_charcode_remove:NTF b
     { $\flat$ \emit_range:w }
     { \emit_range:w }
   }
  #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \emit_do_specs:n { o }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \emit_range:w #1 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #1 } { \textsubscript{#1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\note{A}
\note{A#}
\note{Ab}
\note{A2}
\note{A#2}
\note{Ab2}

\end{document}
```

---

A new implementation with `l3regex` using its splitting capabilities. Some kind of error checking could be implemented for malformed input.

The accidentals are taken from a MusixTeX font using a variant of the method found in [this answer by clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212219/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{musix}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{musix}{m}{n}{
  <-12>   s * [1.5] musix11
  <12-15> s * [1.5] musix13
  <15-18> s * [1.5] musix16
  <18-23> s * [1.5] musix20
  <23->   s * [1.5] musix29
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\musixsym}{m}{%
  \raisebox{.6ex}{\normalfont\usefont{U}{musix}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\mflat{\musixsym{'62}}
\newcommand\mdoubleflat{\musixsym{'63}}
\newcommand\msharp{\musixsym{'64}}
\newcommand\mdoublesharp{\musixsym{'65}}
\newcommand\mnatural{\musixsym{'66}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\note}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_emit_note_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \# } { S } \l_emit_note_tl
  \regex_split:nVN { ([A-G]+) ([Sbn]*) (\d*) } \l_emit_note_tl \l_emit_note_seq
  \seq_item:Nn \l_emit_note_seq { 2 }
  \str_case_x:nn { \seq_item:Nn \l_emit_note_seq { 3 } }
   {
    {S}{\msharp}
    {SS}{\,\mdoublesharp}
    {b}{\mflat}
    {bb}{\mdoubleflat}
    {n}{\mnatural}
   }
  \textsubscript{\seq_item:Nn \l_emit_note_seq { 4 }}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nVN }
\tl_new:N \l_emit_note_tl
\seq_new:N \l_emit_note_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\note{A}
\note{B#}
\note{C##}
\note{Db}
\note{Ebb}
\note{F2}
\note{G#2}
\note{A##2}
\note{Bb2}
\note{Cbb2}
\note{Dn1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, as of LaTeX version 2015/01/01, `\textsubscript` has been incorporated in the kernel.

Comment: No L3 version? Pleeeease. `:)`

Comment: Can you tell me what slow-scanning is, and if this much longer version has any advantages over the solution of Steven B. Segletes?

Comment: @EmitTaste You can also do `\note{A#12}`, with this. It's slow in the sense that I use `\@ifnextchar` to look at the next token.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will use this if I need double accidentals or higher octaves.

Comment: @EmitTaste For double accidentals one needs to extend the macros, but it wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: How about 'n' for natural sign?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I forgot that one, although this is for pitches, not for writing music.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. We often have to specify that a pitch is natural in text.