# How do I produce a double flat symbol (EDIT: )?

Tags: symbols

Maybe my googling skills are failing but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you mean something like `B$\flat\kern-1.4pt\flat$` as found at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Doubleflat.svg/681px-Doubleflat.svg.png?

Comment: Could you please extend a little bit the question? For other users, maybe can be useful to see a picture of the symbol you are after.

Comment: Keywords you might want to use in the question text include: music, lower pitch, bemolle, ♭♭ or  (that should eventually also be in the title)

Comment: This is Unicode U+1D12B so if you have a font with that character (which I don't, apparently) then you could type the character directly as [] in a unicode tex see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment which the OP acknowledged as an accurate rendition, the symbol can be found online, for example, at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Doubleflat.svg/681px-Doubleflat.svg.png.

To recreate this, a simple negative kern between two `\flat` symbols (in math mode) was sufficient to achieve the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
B$\flat\kern-1.4pt\flat$
\end{document}
```

[image]

egreg correctly points out that using a point kern will need adjustment if the font size is changed.  The problem can be somewhat alleviated by using `\mkern-2.4mu` as egreg suggests in principle, or using kerning units of ex or em, in preference to pt.  Nonetheless, it is likely that rendering in different font sizes will still require some fine tuning of the kern amount, as it can be verified that `\tiny B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$` does not render with the same relative spacing as `B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$`.

Adopting the `\mkern` approach, the example below shows that an `\ooalign` method shown on the right is slightly superior to the negative kern method shown on the left, at the `scriptsize` and `\tiny` sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering
{\tiny neg. kern ooalign}

B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$
B\ooalign{$\flat$\cr$\mkern4.4mu\flat$}

\small B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$
B\ooalign{$\flat$\cr$\mkern4.4mu\flat$}

\footnotesize B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$
B\ooalign{$\flat$\cr$\mkern4.4mu\flat$}

\scriptsize B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$
B\ooalign{$\flat$\cr$\mkern4.4mu\flat$}

\tiny B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$
B\ooalign{$\flat$\cr$\mkern4.4mu\flat$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\mkern-2mu` (find the correct amount) is much preferable to `\kern-1.4pt`, because it would work at any font size.

Comment: @egreg While I certainly understand your intent, the expression `\tiny B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$` does not render the same relative spacing as `B$\flat\mkern-2.4mu\flat$`.  I guess my point is that different font size will require tuning in any event.

Comment: It does at all other sizes. The problem is that the em is wider at five point size than it would be if linear scaling was used.

Comment: @egreg Combining `\mkern` with `\ooalign` seems to work best at the smallest font sizes, in preference to the negative kern.

Answer (score 5):

The [`musixtex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex) package [provides a font](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex-fonts) (in five sizes and only one variant) which has the symbol (instead of a »3«). Here is one possibility to use it in text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{musix}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{musix}{m}{n}{%
  <-12>   musix11
  <12-15> musix13
  <15-18> musix16
  <18-23> musix20
  <23->   musix29
}{}%
% Not strictly necessary but convenient:
\newcommand*\musix{\usefont{U}{musix}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmusix}{\musix}

\newcommand*\doubleflat{\raisebox{.6ex}{\textmusix{3}}}
\newcommand*\doublesharp{\raisebox{.6ex}{\textmusix{5}}}

\begin{document}

B\textmusix{3}B\textmusix{5}B\par
B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B

\large B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\Large B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\LARGE B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\huge B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B

\small B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\footnotesize B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\scriptsize B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B\par
\tiny B\doubleflat B\doublesharp B

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d12b/index.htm) for this and here are the [four fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d12b/fontsupport.htm) I could find to set this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
A{\fontspec{code2001_0.ttf}\symbol{"1D12B}}B{\fontspec{freeserif.ttf}\symbol{"1D12B}}D{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"1D12B}}E{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1D12B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use the package [`lilyglyphs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/lilyglyphs) for this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % for textsubscript

\begin{document}
A\flatflat{}B\textsubscript{\flatflat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget about the first Unicode-compliant music font, Bravura: http://www.smufl.org/fonts/

Comment: @AndrewCashner Thank you for the input. Won't install this font on the machine I am setting at, but I would be happy, if you include an image. Just edit my post and mark it CW.

Comment: Actually I just tried it and even with "Bravura Text", which supposedly is designed for use in running text, the symbols are too small and raised too far above the baseline, so they require manual adjustment. Also, it turns out Bravura's double-flat symbol is really just to flats smashed together with kerning, as in several answers here.