# Showing music flat glyph inline with text

Tags: music, lilypond

Talking about music using lilypond-book and LaTeX.

It's going great. Now I'm trying to use lilypond snippet simply to display the `\flat` glyph.

```
I want to show you what 
\begin{lilypond}
\paper {
    left-margin = .1\in
    right-margin = .1\in
}
 \new ChordNames \with {
  \override ChordName #'font-size = #-3
} {bes}
\end{lilypond} and 
\begin{lilypond}
\paper {
    left-margin = .1\in
    right-margin = .1\in
}
 \new ChordNames \with {
  \override ChordName #'font-size = #-3
} {bis}
\end{lilypond}
```

What it looks like is this:

[image: Picture of text and musical elements inline.]

The `\paper` directive doesn't seem to be doing anything.

There must be an easier way.

Comment: Why not `B$\flat$` and `B$\sharp$`?

Comment: Because I needed to do way more work than necessary! Thank you. What are those dollar signs all about?

Comment: `$` switches to math mode and back (this is *very* basic LaTeX knowledge!). Per default `\flat` and `\sharp` can be used only in math mode. You can leave them away and see for yourself what happens.

Comment: I expected that it would be some very basic LaTeX knowledge. Do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: Another more powerful alternative: `\usepackage[chords]{leadsheets}` and then `\chordname{B#}` and `\chordname{Bb}` (this also correctly transforms stuff like `\chordname{Eb7(#9)}`.

Comment: Wow. Great. Falling deeper and deeper in love with TeX.

Comment: Here is a related fun question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148355/writing-musical-pitches

Answer (score 2):

The leadsheets package is perfect for my needs. The `$` shortcut to go into math mode and have those symbols available is very handy: `B$\sharp$`, but the whole package offers a lot more options. Here's [the docs](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/leadsheets/leadsheets_en.pdf).

```
\usepackage[full]{leadsheets}
\useleadsheetslibraries{musicsymbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{changemargin}{-1cm}{-1cm} 
\lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{omeimhreem.ly}
\end{changemargin}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\label{fig:Om eim hreem shreem kleem saw sat chit ekam Bramah}
\caption[Om eim hreem shreem kleem saw sat chit ekam Bramah]{The chords look complex at a glance, but it's fairly simple. You can just play B$\flat$ and D with an F note below them for the \writechord{Bb/F} chord, then move the F down one note to E which makes the \writechord{Bbsus/E}. The D minor over F is just moving the E up one and the B$\flat$ one down to A. \par
\begin{lilypond}
snippet = \relative c' {<f bes d>1 <e bes' d> <f a d> }
\score { 
\snippet 
\layout { 
     #(layout-set-staff-size 14)
     }
}
\end{lilypond} }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image: picture of music]