# Persian accidentals in LaTeX (music)

Tags: texlive

Can somebody help me with writing Persian (Iranian) music accidentals including “Koron” and “Sori” in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

Without the context provided by a minimum working example, it is hard to say how this would be implemented in the OP's context.  However, constructing a koron is straightforward, by stacking a `|` and a `>`.

This MWE derives from [Writing musical pitches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148355/writing-musical-pitches/148357#148357)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\koron{\kern-.7pt\raisebox{-1pt}{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{2.1pt}{\scriptstyle|}{\mkern.7mu\scriptscriptstyle
  >}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}\kern-.7pt}
\newcommand\note[1]{\xnote[#1]}
\def\xnote[#1#2#3]{#1\ifx b#2$\flat_#3$\else\ifx#2##$\sharp_#3$\else
  \ifx#2\koron\koron$_#3$\else$_#2$\fi\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\note{Eb3}
\note{A2}
\note{F#4}
\note{F\koron2}
\rlap{\rule[2pt]{20pt}{.4pt}}
$\flat\sharp\koron$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Most kind Steven, hi. I have finded the link of the image of the user: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27479

Comment: Thanks for supplying such a nice trick to write quarter tones in MUSIXTEX environment.

Comment: @Mehdi If this answer is wholly satisfactory, such that you don't need to wait upon other possible answers, you could, if you wish, click the check mark to the left of my question, which will indicate to other readers that, of the several possible answers given, this one you found best answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LilyPond (e.g., via `\usepackage{lyluatex}`), then there are some solutions on the web. For instance, a simple idea here: [koron symbol in LilyPond](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114084/defining-new-commands-in-lilypond-for-koron-symbol)

If you are interested in more elaborate (automated) approaches, here is another attempt:
[persian.ly by Kees van den Doel](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Re-Persian-musical-koron-and-sori-td43022i40.html#a43041)

Also I know of a Unicode font in which the koron and sori symbols are incorporated: [Standard Music Font Layout (SMuFL)](https://www.w3.org/2019/03/smufl13/tables/persian-accidentals.html)